# Linux Filter Big log File for reporting

Tags: regex, linux, logging, analysis

I have a Big Log of more than 26000 files and each file will have the  content like below.. I need to Exclude all the lines which has 404 with JSON. in the below case I need to get the last line since that is the content which is having 404 and not JSON. Any help in writing filter regular expression? Linux Gurus help is appreciated..

**- Error   pbmzjYvLFIlLeth6mN2Yox9DH4vap1hcFHuJgNosd0XHVSxGdRcrWw==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.004   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.213.22   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.jpg 404**

## Version: 1.0

## Fields: date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) x-edge-result-type x-edge-request-id x-host-header cs-protocol cs-bytes time-taken x-forwarded-for ssl-protocol ssl-cipher x-edge-response-result-type

2015-07-28  11:34:57    MAD50   658 124.13.170.152  GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   tdlmnsfrOCxOelbe82y3kIp_QfbBF7S3dDCn4rHR65JOMkOtZu4dzA==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.004   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:53    SIN3    659 14.192.214.93   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   5r0xsHnxLY5TePeJ6ZfKvuHrhQnbd2lbWtDQosEXLj4Z7TZ5N68ZhA==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.002   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:53    SIN3    659 14.192.213.198  GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   koGGTK2mc2dDS3XvABS0zAeqheH52toNmJgIqAh5A0TYKIZL6qsgRw==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:54    SIN3    659 14.192.208.27   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   bvLIe540oNMCeZ0QpOmX1OKoClgNgvSWppGuOmgVS85WnAXKJ1ryDg==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.002   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:54    SIN3    659 210.19.26.33    GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   6Wl5xeCZArNN3WGaIGOA6XjUqZHEiENbWOmChiMZPayefDuLtC8WrA==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:54    SIN3    659 121.121.62.92   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   WLn7heBO3PvvVW1vt365EVXqoD440Byy6Qh6RYYazSyPBZUxwsS0Jg==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:54    SIN3    659 14.192.213.9    GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   hTbk9HE5nyFSla1DmeC1D1jhuMtoUY6E7QQvyf0v1YyJ1GBp-I40bw==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.213.250  GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;HD) -   -   Error   avWgysZyGeGXdVxZHLfP5uLJ4ie5Hx8pa6ZJC5GHXfvOkyEXXp8o0g==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.211.78   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   wBepjCn58o9AiTifvtrCprkjdAdg--zsLTsjDpUBkxnEU5tahmJxxQ==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.004   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 121.121.101.4   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   YZ07B5vu7L4I3aoTcBXF5rcH8Dwrv5a77xRqqelkQqvQhYLDnkrKWg==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.001   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.208.156  GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404 -   NDS%2520VM%2520Engine/002%2520Apr%252004%25202014%2520(OSD:%252032%2520;SD) -   -   Error   pbmzjYvLFIlLeth6mN2Yox9DH4vap1hcFHuJgNosd0XHVSxGdRcrWw==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.004   -   -   -   Error
2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.213.22   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.json   404

- Error   pbmzjYvLFIlLeth6mN2Yox9DH4vap1hcFHuJgNosd0XHVSxGdRcrWw==    pdl.astro.com.my    http    151 0.004   -   -   -   Error
  2015-07-28  11:34:55    SIN3    659 14.192.213.22   GET d2v2sjgehuhalt.cloudfront.net   /thumbnail/mediaInfo_211.jpg 404

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse big HTTP logs, you should go with [visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/), and if you want a JSON output, well since this community is about coding, you could extend it to do so.

Otherwise, for your original question, here is a way with `awk`:

```
awk '$NF == 404 && $(NF -1) ~ /\.json$/ { next; } {print}' /path/to/yourfile.log

$NF == 404  # the last field is 404
$(NF -1)    # the field before the last
~ /\.json$/ # ends with .json
{ next; }   # skip this line
{ print }   # print anything else
```